# How to choose default option in NSComboBox or NSPopUpButton?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm developing a Mac OS App using Xcode 10 and Swift 4.2.

For a particular scenario, I want to provide the users with are four options but for most users the first option is enough. So I want the first option to be default and when the user wants to change, he can choose from the other three. 
I'm trying to achieve the same using NSComboBox or NSPopUpButton but I'm struck.

In the below image, the first is a combo box and the next is a popup button.

[image: Combo Box and Pop Up Button]

If the user clicks on "Default", I need to call a method. If the user Clicks on the arrow mark, I need to display the list of options, the user will select one option and then I have to call the same method.

Below is the image showing list of options, if arrow is clicked.

[image: Combo box showing options]

The problem is that ComboBox inherits from NSControl but when I set action to it, the method call is not working and PopUpButton lists the options, irrespective of whether I click on "Default" label or on the arrow.

The main objective is that, it should be only one mouse click by the user to choose the default option and two clicks to change the option. 
How to achieve it using ComboBox, PopUpButton or any other object?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- If the option is not performed immediately create a property and set it to the default option in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`. Set the corresponding index in the combo box / popup button. Observe [`selectionDidChangeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscombobox/1436745-selectiondidchangenotification). If the user changes the option set the property in the notification action.
- If the option is performed immediately use Cocoa Bindings and bind `selectedIndex` or `selectedObject` to an appropriate `dynamic` property. Set the default value in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`. Add the `didSet` property observer and perform the option.

Both NSCombobox and NSPopUpButton work similar.